# What are methods used for?

Tags: java

I am a complete newbie to programming and Java.  I am learning Java in school and as my teacher is lecturing I understand what things do,and this may be a dumb question, but I was just curious why can't you just write everything in the main() method?  Why do we need to call methods for certain tasks?

Keep in mind I am a beginner.  Thanks!

EDIT: I guess this question will be deleted soon for the broadness or the fact that I could've done more research apparently?

I've been watching many tutorials on this and trying to find an answer, but could not.  I thought methods were ABSOLUTELY necessary to write some programs.  I just needed a clear concise answer as to what was the general point of using other methods if you could just write everything in main

Comment: For re-useability and maintainability.

Comment: Why don't we just code in assembler?

Comment: You can write everything in the `main()` method. Of course just because you can doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: You'll probably learn over time that you want to decompose everything as much as possible.  This will not only help those that come after you, but will help your future self in understanding what you did.

Comment: it would take just a google search to get an insight of what functions are and what they do.And please read this:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Comment: Write Java program - *any* program that does a "non trivial task". Then you'll know what methods are good for and why writing everything in main is not a viable option.

Comment: Your question is a bit over-broad, but remember that computer programs are not to be written to be best understood by a computer (although they must at least be understood by a computer) but to be best understood by man. So we divide problems and conquer them, step by step, which is what methods allow. Imagine planning a 100 story sky scraper and having to create a separate blue print for each floor -- that would be unrealistic and overly complicated. Instead you create a general floor blueprint, and then modify it as needed -- you divide and conquer.

Comment: Note that our closing your question is no comment on the merit of your question -- it is a good question indeed -- but rather on whether it is an appropriate stackoverflow question, and I believe that it isn't. Please have a look at the help section to see more on what makes appropriate questions for this site. Much luck and look forward to seeing you around here!

Comment: It's mainly to do with not repeating yourself 1000000 times, which makes the general idea behind your code much more clearer. Though as @HovercraftFullOfEels says, unfortunately this question isn't really suited for Stack Overflow in its current state.

Answer (score 2):

In theory you could write the whole thing in `main` (not really since you have to call native Java methods to make your program do something useful), however method helps you reusing your code and organize it better.

Imagine that you need to perform a complex computation based on an input value and the implementation takes a bunch of lines of code. If you need to perform that computation multiple times, you could either copy/paste all these lines of code or you could encapsulate the algorithm in a function and simply call that method when needed.

What's wrong with copy/pasting? Well let's imagine you had a bug in the algorithm or that you simply need to change it, you have to remember everywhere you copy/pasted the lines of code and fix the algorithm, rather than simply fixing a single method.

Anyway, that's just the top of the iceberg, I haven't even mentionned code comprehension, testability and flexibility. Also, it's not only about methods but about Object-oritented programming advantages.

Comment: Reusing it as in looking back on it later?

Comment: Downvote? What is not accurate?

Comment: @user2949150 Well it depends, it can simply avoid code duplication for repetitive tasks, or if you are designing an API that you/others can use in another project, you could see this as *being reused later*.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly *could* do that. But by breaking the tasks down into smaller self-contained bits, you gain:

1) Understandability: Someone wanting to understand what the program does at a high level can 'get it' by looking at a smaller number of lines, without having to digest all the details at once.

2) Testability: You can test each method's tasks to make sure it is doing what is required, without having to test the whole thing.

3) Reusability: Often things you put in methods can be useful in other contexts. No need to rewrite when you can just call.

There are more, but they follow on from these same ideas.